# Why is the nested macro not unfolded?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I am using nested macro under `gcc-9.3.1`.

Here is the code.

```
#define A(_name) _name, _name, _name

#define P(_1, _2, _name, ...) _name

#define B(...) P(__VA_ARGS__, A(something))(__VA_ARGS__)

B(k)
```

I expected the `B(k)` converted to `P(k, something, something, something)(k)` at first and then converted into `something(k)`.

However, compilier told me that two arguments were too few for `P`, which meant that  `A(something)` was not unfolded.

Why is that? And how can I make it unfolded?

Comment: You should have a look at GNU's [Macro Expansion](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Macro-Expansion.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B(k)` expands to `P(k, A(something))(k)` which then undergoes recursive expansion.  The first thing it finds there is `P`, which doesn't have enough arguments.

If you want this to work the way I think you do, you need to arrange for `A` to expand before `P`.  You can do that by adding explicit indirect `EXPAND` macros:

```
#define EXPAND(...)   __VA_ARGS__

#define B(...) EXPAND(P EXPAND((__VA_ARGS__, A(something))))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

This way, `P` won't be recognized as a macro (no following `(`) until after the inner `EXPAND` is expanded (which will also expand A).  You need the outer `EXPAND` to explicitly expand `P` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! That works! One more question, if I write ```#define A(_name) _name(somthing)```, ```#define B(_name) do(_name)``` and ```A(B)```, then ```A(B)``` will be unfolded to ```B(somthing)```. This is similar to the previous condition but its inner expression would be unfolded. Why is that?

Comment: It is expanded as it is a macro invocation.  With the example I gave, in the first expansion, `P` is not a macro invocation as it is not followed by a `(` (yet).

Comment: I think I got it! Thank you very much